# cpp-ethereum/aleth listening to smart contract events problem

Tags: http, ethereum, web3js

We are working on a fork of ethereum from cpp-ethereum/aleth, and I am wondering how to listen to contract events if websocket is not available?
in web3 there is web3.eth.subscribe but it does not work if there is no websocket, since only HTTP provider is available.

How do we suppose to listen to contract events without it? call eth_getlogs with 'pending' then how do we get triggered when an event happened?

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the major differences between HTTP and WSS connections.

- HTTP connection opens for each operation and then closes
- WSS connection opens once and then transfers messages without closing the connection

So if you need to use HTTP connection, you'll need to poll the results of `eth_getlogs`. Polling is constantly asking for updates, e.g. each second. Mind that with a short interval, you'll most likely run into rate limits of your provider.

Logs are published as a result of mining, so they are not yet available in the mempool (i.e. the `pending` option). You'll need to query each `latest` block (or its number).